# Closed question on p-values

Tags: p-value

Working on some closed questions on the p-value theory, I stumbled upon this one.

> What does the p-value tell about a parameter estimate?
>
> 1. the margin of error
> 2. the likelihood of the data
> 3. the impact on the model's prediction
> 4. the probability that is the product of noise

Now, I'm convinced that the 1st one is wrong, but apart from that I'm not really sure how to connect the definition of p-values to one of the remainings. The first question is: is there one of them which is actually correct? And if that is the case, which one?

According to the wikipedia definition, p-value is the probability of obtaining test results at least as extreme as the results actually observed, assuming that the null hypothesis is correct. This leads me to somehow  think that we can intepret that as the likelihood of the data, but I'm not actually sure, since p-values are probabilities, not likelihood functions. Meaning that the only possible answer to this should be the 4th one. Still, I'm not that convinced.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It is difficult to determine what "product of noise" would even mean.  It doesn't sound like any kind of probability, though, which implies if in any interpretation it has some relationship to a p-value, it must be an indirect one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say "none of the above".  1 2 and 3 are definitely wrong and 4 seems to be some sort of badly stated "arose by chance" thing, but it doesn't mention that the null has to be true and it doesn't define "noise".  The Wikipedia definition is OK, but it should mention that the sample has to be randomly selected.